# Problem with multiple decimal points (Python)

Tags: python

I have having a bit of a problem:

I am trying to convert these numbers:

-0.2179,
-8.742.754.508,
1.698.516.678,

to

-0.22,
-8.74,
1.70,

But I am really not sure how I do this, when the number of decimal points is different?

I have tried .split('.') but its difficult with changing decimal points.

I was wondering if you guys had any pointers for this small problem? Kind regard.

```
for number in data.fundreturn:
    
        new_number = number.split('.')[0]
        fund.append(new_number)
   
    
for number in data.bitcoinreturn:
    
        new_number = number.split('.')[0]
        bitcoin.append(new_number)
```

but then I get 0, 8, and 1

The code snippet basically is me going through each column and trying to covert the values.

Comment: Where do your number come from ? Are your number strings in a file or a list of float ?
Give an example of `data.fundreturn`

Comment: From CSV file, floats

data.fundreturn is the numbers above in a column in my dataframe. I am trying to convert them, but these having different numbers of decimal points

Comment: From CSV file ok. 
What's currently the type of data.fundreturn ? list[str] or list[float] ?
Reading your example II suppose a list of string.

Comment: That's a _really_ weird format. Is `.` being used both as a decimal separator _and_ as a thousands separator? How do we know that `-8.742.754.508` equals minus eight and a bit, and not minus eight thousand something, or minus eight million something, or minus eight billion something? Which locale is this?

Comment: I was told that these represent the daily % changes in the price of the asset. So -8.742.754 would be -8.7% daily change

I agree the format is weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution takes into account the decimal part after the first dot and ignores the rest of the string.

```py
def convert(number: str) -> float:
    n = number.split(".")
    return float(n[0]) if len(n)<2 else float(f"{n[0]}.{n[1]}")

convert("32")  # 32.0
convert("-8.742.754.508")  # -8.742
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, the split function would be enough as a solution if used like this:

```
data = ["-0.2179", "-8.742.754.508", "1.698.516.678"]
fund = []
for number in data:
    split = number.split('.')
    integer_part = split[0]
    fractional_part = ''.join([split[i] for i in range(1, len(split))])
    new_number = float('.'.join((integer_part, fractional_part)))
    # rounding to two decimal points
    new_number = round(new_number, 2)
    fund.append(new_number)

print(fund)
```

Comment: I get index out of range for this

Comment: I edited the code, is it fixed now?